# Is there such a thing as ‘class bloat’ - i.e. too many classes causing inefficiencies?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

E.g. let’s consider I have the following classes:

- `Item`
- `ItemProperty` which would include objects such as `Colour` and `Size`.  There's a relation-property of the `Item` class which lists all of the `ItemProperty` objects applicable to this Item (i.e. for one item you might need to specify the Colour and for another you might want to specify the Size).
- `ItemPropertyOption` would include objects such as `Red`, `Green` (for `Colour`) and `Big`, `Small` (for `Size`).

Then an `Item` Object would relate to an `ItemProperty`, whereas an `ItemChoice` Object would relate to an `ItemPropertyOption` (and the `ItemProperty` which the `ItemPropertyOption` refers to could be inferred).

The reason for this is so I could then make use of queries much more effectively. i.e. give me all item-choices which are `Red`. It would also allow me to use the Parse Dashboard to quickly add elements to the site as I could easily specify more `ItemProperty`s and `ItemPropertyOption`s, rather than having to add them in the codebase.

This is just a small example and there's many more instances where I'd like to use classes so that 'options' for various drop-downs in forms are in the database and can easily be added and edited by me, rather than hard-coded.

1) I’ll probably be doing this in a similar way for 5+ more similar kinds of class-structures

2) there could be hundreds of nested properties that I want to access via ‘inverse querying’

So, I can think of 2 potential causes of inefficiency and wanted to know if they’re founded:

- Is having lots of classes inefficient?
- Is back-querying against nested classes inefficient?

The other option I can think of — if ‘class-bloat’ really is a problem — is to make fields on parent classes that, instead of being nested across other classes (that represent further properties, as above), just representing them as a nested JSON property directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job of designing is to render in object descriptions truths about the world that are relevent to the system's requirements.  In the world of the OP's "items", it's a fact that items have color, and it's a relevant fact because users care about an item's color. You'd only call a system inefficient if it consumes computing resources that it doesn't *need* to consume.

So, for something like a configurator, the fact that we have items, and that those items have properties, and those properties have an enumerable set of possible values sounds like a perfectly rational design.

Is it inefficient or "bloated"? The only place I'd raise doubt is in the explicit assertion that items have properties.  Of course they do, but that's natively true of javascript objects and parse entities.

In other words, you might be able to get along with just item and several flavors of propertyOptions: e.g. Item has an attribute called "colorProperty" that is a pointer to an instance of "ColorProperty" (whose instances have a name property like 'red', 'green', etc. and maybe describe other pertinent facts, like a more precise description in RGB form).

There's nothing wrong with lots of classes if they represent relevant truth.  Do that first.  You might discover empirically that your design is too resource consumptive (I doubt you will in this case), at which point we'd start looking for cheats to be somehow skinnier.  But do it the right way first, cheat later only if you must.

Comment: This sounds like sensible advice. I will probably follow this for now. Another question which is important for going down this road - is back-querying against nested classes inefficient? I.e. writing a query to find out which `ItemProperty` an `ItemPropertyOption` belongs to.

Comment: That's a single query if you have the option object in hand.  And it's straight forward i.e. `itemPropQuery.equal('propValue', somePropOption)`, but you might need a preliminary query to get `somePropOption` in hand.  Is it inefficient?  As I say above, inefficient means doing something unnecessary in order to achieve the desired function.  If you need such a query, then this approach is the straight line way to do it.  I'm still a little skeptical that you'll need this (or the intermediary "ItemProperty" class)

Answer (score 0):

> Is having lots of classes inefficient?

It's certainly inefficient for poor humans who have to remember what all those classes do and how they're related to each other. It takes time to write all those classes in the first place, and every line that you write is a line that has to be maintained.

Beyond that, there's certainly *some* cost for each class in any OOP language, and creating more classes than you really need will mean that you're paying more than you need to for the work that you're doing, which is pretty much the definition of inefficient.

> I’ll probably be doing this in a similar way for 5+ more similar kinds of class-structures

Maybe you could spend some time thinking about the similarity between these cases and come up with a single set of more flexible classes that you can use in all those cases. Writing general code is harder than writing very specific code, but if you do a good job you'll recoup the extra effort many times over through reuse.